# Python retrieve filepath of where file was copied from

Tags: python, directory, copy, filepath

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the file path of where a file was copied from. As in, let's say I have 'FileA' in dir1, and I copy it to dir2. Is there any way (preferably in Python) to examine the copied file in dir2 and retrieve the dir1 file path where the file was copied from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do it by just examining the file in dir2. Such information can be in system or user logs or something like this but not in the destination file.